# Join on rows that have maximum value in Access 2016

Tags: sql, ms-access

Trying to select all students in Access 2016, and join one plan for each student. It works fine, but it's not the most recent plan that's selected...
If I ran only the subquery for a specific student_id it's working and the most recent plan is selected.

```
SELECT dbo_Student.*, a.*
FROM dbo_Student LEFT JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM dbo_Plan ORDER BY Year 
DESC, Version DESC)  AS a ON dbo_Student.ID = a.student_id
WHERE Archived = FALSE
ORDER BY Name;
```

**Edit**
This is the closest I got so far thanks to C perkins:

```
SELECT s.*, p.*
FROM dbo_Student s LEFT JOIN
(SELECT p1.* 
 FROM dbo_Plan p1 INNER JOIN 
      (SELECT p2.student_id, MAX(p2.ID) As MaxID
       FROM dbo_Plan p2
       GROUP BY p2.student_id
      ) pAgg
      ON p1.student_id = pAgg.student_id 
         AND p1.ID = pAgg.MaxID
) p
ON s.id = p.student_id
WHERE Archived = FALSE
ORDER BY Name;
```

This assumes that the maximum ID is the most recent Plan (Year DESC, Version DESC). And it works almost always, but it's not failsafe.

Comment: did u try to use "inner" join?

Comment: your subquery only returns one record in total. You want one that returns one record _per student_.

Comment: @ErayBalkanli Yes, but there are students without a plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that your original query would imply that there may be multiple `Versions` for a single `Year` (`ORDER BY Year DESC, Version DESC`); I would suggest the following:

```
select dbo_student.*, b.*
from
    dbo_student left join
    (
        select a.* from dbo_plan a inner join
        (
            select q.student_id, q.year, max(q.version) as v
            from dbo_plan q inner join
            (
                select p.student_id, max(p.year) as y
                from dbo_plan p
                group by p.student_id
            ) s on q.student_id = s.student_id and q.year = s.y
            group by q.student_id, q.year
        ) t on
        a.student_id = t.student_id and 
        a.year = t.year and
        a.version = t.v
    ) b on dbo_student.id = b.student_id
where 
    archived = false
order by 
    name
```

The innermost query obtains the maximum `Year` per `Student_ID`, the parent query then obtains the maximum `Version` for such `Year` per `Student_ID`, to which the original table is joined so that all fields may be output.

Comment: Yes, there are multiple Versions for each year and I need the most recent one for the most recent Year - if there is a plan at all. But with your code I got (translated): The Join expression is not supported.

Comment: @user3336208 Apologies - I had omitted a `group by` expression and needed to restructure the join - I have edited my answer above.

Answer (score 2):

The TOP predicate applies to an entire query and that original subquery was not properly selecting records for each student.  *The original query was technically not working properly even when it was run for a specific student_id.*  Perhaps it seemed like it was working only because many student_ids coincidentally have the same "most recent year", but that inner subquery was always selecting a *single arbitrary record* which sorted with the most recent year.  Moral of this query: **There is more to a valid query than code that just returns what looks correct.**

The following version is compatible with Access SQL.  The inner-most *aggregate* subquery gets the most recent year for "each student" (`GROUP BY p2.student_id`).  The next subquery then gets the full plan record which matches the most recent year.

```
SELECT s.*, p.*
FROM dbo_Student s LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT p1.* 
     FROM pdbo_Plan p1 INNER JOIN
          (SELECT p2.student_id, 
                 pAgg2.MaxYear,
                 MAX(pAgg2.version) As MaxVersion
           FROM pdbo_Plan p2 INNER JOIN
                (SELECT p3.student_id, MAX(p3.year) As MaxYear
                 FROM dbo_Plan p3
                 GROUP BY p3.student_id
                ) pAgg2
                ON p2.student_id = pAgg2.student_id 
                   AND p2.year = pAgg2.MaxYear
           GROUP BY p2.student_id, pAgg2.MaxYear
          ) pAgg1
          ON p1.student_id = pAgg1.student_id 
             AND p1.year = pAgg1.MaxYear
             AND p1.version = pAgg1.MaxVersion
    ) p
    ON s.id = p.student_id
WHERE Archived = FALSE
ORDER BY Name;
```

Comment: I get multiple rows with the same student with this. And not the most recent plan only. I need the most recent Year and Version.

Comment: Kudos to Lee Mac for recognizing the version requirement in the first place.  I also updated the code to include the version, now essentially the same code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want :

```
SELECT s.*, p.*
FROM dbo_Student s LEFT JOIN
     dbo_Plan p
     ON p.student_id = s.id AND
        p.year = (SELECT MAX(p1.year)
                  FROM dbo_Plan p1
                  WHERE p1.student_id = p.student_id
                 )
WHERE Archived = FALSE
ORDER BY Name;
```

Comment: A subquery directly within the ON expression is not allowed in Access SQL.  Access does allow some variation in the ON expression, but both sides of the comparison expression must include a column from the respective tables.  It is possible to JOIN to a subquery but only as source table.